Using hostnames in launchSettings.json doesn't write out the hostname in logs?
When a hostname is specified for local development in the launchSettings.json
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "applicationUrl": "https://mysite.local:6200;http://mysite.local:5200",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }

This results in the logs not writing out the hostname:

[10:28:36 INF] Now listening on: https://[::]:6100
[10:28:36 INF] Now listening on: http://[::]:5100

If I revert back to localhost I get:

[10:28:36 INF] Now listening on: https://localhost:6100
[10:28:36 INF] Now listening on: http://locahost:5100

Is it possible to get the custom domain logged out?

By default, Kestrel logs its bindings using the actual IP addresses it listens on. So the log will not show the domain name (mysite.local), it logs the IP address format ([::] for IPv6 or 127.0.0.1 for IPv4).
A workaround to log the domain name is to create custom middleware like below:
public class LogDomainMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<LogDomainMiddleware> _logger;

    public LogDomainMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<LogDomainMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var hostName = context.Request.Host.Value;
        _logger.LogInformation($"Request received for domain: {hostName}");
        await _next(context);
    }
}

Register the middleware in Program.cs:
app.UseMiddleware<LogDomainMiddleware>(); 

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run(); 

